# Photos app not visible

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

A friend has a iPhone 6 iOS 10.x and we cannot find the photos app. She has activated iCloud storage for photos in settings but we cannot find how to see the albums. I am an Androd user and have zero iOS knowledge.

Comment: Swipe right at the Home screen to pull up the Search screen. Start typing 'ph' and if the app is present on the iPhone it should show up with its icon on the left and if it has been moved into a folder, the name of the folder will appear to the right.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! The biggest win you can provide is working with them to be sure they know what’s being backed up and how recent the last successful backup was. I’ll answer the question in the answer section of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not an app that’s [designed to be removed](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/remove-apps-iph248b543ca/ios), so it’s either hidden and you can use spotlight to search for which folder it moved to or the database that records where apps are visible is corrupted.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204221

For the former you want to be sure you have a good backup and then restart the device to see if Spotlight can rebuild. If there is no free space, remove some content and restart again.

For the latter, get a good backup and restore the device.